# Adjust position x-axis title

Tags: r

I would like to adjust the position of the x-axis title of my generated graph. Note that the word `titlex` is way below the graph, however I would like to adjust it higher. How to do this?

```
data(USArrests)
titlex <- dist(scale(USArrests), method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(titlex, method = "ward.D2")
plot(hc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative would be to remove the line for xlab through the title function.

```
plot(hc, xlab="")
title(xlab = "titlex", line = 0)
```

[image]